# how to divide a numpy array of coordinates using a surface

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays both having coordinates of some points. One array has the coordinates of a cutting planar surface (`cutting_surf`) and another one has coordinates of some points (`points`):

```
cutting_surf=np.array([[3., 1., 3.], [2., 1., 1.],[3., 2., 3.],\
                       [2., 2., 1.], [3., 3., 3.], [2., 3., 1.]])
points=np.array([[1.2, 3., 3.], [4., 1., 2.], [2.2, 2., 1.], [1.2, 1.5, 3.], [2.5, 1.5, 3.],\
                 [2.9, 1., 3.], [2.9, 2., 2.9], [4., 3., 1.9], [3.2, 1.2, 3.], [2.2, 3., 3.5],\
                 [2.5, 3., 3.], [2.2, 1.5, 3.5]])
```

Then, I want to remove some redundant coordinates from `points`. These coordinates are too close to the coordinates from `cutting_surf`. I used the following code to do so:

```
to_be_removed=points[np.where(np.min(distance.cdist(cutting_surf, points),axis=0)<0.5)[0],:]
cleaned_result= npi.difference(points, to_be_removed) # it removes that close points
```

After that, my final plan is to divid my `points` array into two ones. In fact, I want to really cut `points` array using `cutting_surf`. I mean I want to get my `cleaned_result` as:

```
[np.array([[2.5, 3., 3.],
          [2.5, 1.5, 3.],
          [1.2, 3., 3.],
          [1.2, 1.5, 3.],
          [2.2, 3., 3.5],
          [2.2, 1.5, 3.5]])
 np.array([[4. , 3. , 1.9],
           [4. , 1. , 2. ]])]
```

My fig shows the distribution of coordinates that I have. I presented just some simple coordinates here and by sorting them based on their `x` values I can divide the array into two one but in reality it is much more complicates. I think the only way is creating the surface using `cutting_surf` coordinates and then separating two clusters. I tried creating the surface using four corners of `cutting_surf` but I have no idea how to cluster my points using this surface:

```
def plane_from_points(cutting_surf):
    centroid = np.mean(cutting_surf, axis=0)
    _, eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.svd(cutting_surf - centroid)
    if eigenvalues[1] < PRECISION:
        raise ValueError("Points are aligned, can't define a plane")
    normal = eigenvectors[2]
    d = -np.dot(centroid, normal)
    plane = np.append(normal, d)
    thickness = eigenvalues[2]
    return plane, thickness
```

In advance, I appreciate any help and contribution.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the issue correctly, but might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line (You would have to do that in 3D, using a plane instead of a line, evidently.)

Comment: Dear @Hans, thanks for sending me the link. My problem is to somehow similar to that but a little bit more complicated because I am doing it in 3D and also in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have already done the filtering by distance, so I will focus on the aspect of separating the "clean" points.

Please note: In your example, the six `cutting_surf` points are on two parallel lines, hence they span a plane - if your surface is not a simple plane, this simple approach will not work.

Geometrically speaking:

1. We determine a vector `orth` orthogonal to the `cutting_surf` plane.
2. For each point `p` of the `points`, we determine the dot product between `orth` and `p` relative to some point on the plane. The sign of the dot product is the "side" of the plane: All points with a positive sign are on one side, all points with a negative sign on the other. (And those with a zero dot product are on the plane.)

For the first part, we describe the `cutting_surf` plane in terms of two normed vectors `v1` and `v2`, and the orthogonal vector `o` is just the cross product of these. This is basically an adaptation of [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030699/1016514):

```
import numpy as np
# surface points slightly reordered
cutting_surf = np.array([[3., 1., 3.], [3., 2., 3.], [3., 3., 3.],
                         [2., 1., 1.], [2., 2., 1.], [2., 3., 1.]])

# take three points, not all on the same line
# -> two vectors for the plane
corner = cutting_surf[0]
v1 = np.subtract(cutting_surf[1], corner)
v1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)

v2 = np.subtract(cutting_surf[3], corner)
v2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)

orth = np.cross(v1, v2)
```

For the second part, take each "clean" point, determine its difference to some point on the plane, and group by the sign of the dot product with `orth`:

```
cleaned_points = np.array([[2.5, 3., 3.], [2.5, 1.5, 3.], [1.2, 3., 3.],
      [1.2, 1.5, 3.], [2.2, 3., 3.5], [2.2, 1.5, 3.5], [4. , 3. , 1.9],
      [4. , 1. , 2. ]])

one, other = [], []
for p in cleaned_points:
    # point relative to our corner:
    p_moved = np.subtract(p, corner)
    d = np.dot(orth, p_moved)
    # in case of doubt, check for d == 0 here
    (one if d < 0 else other).append(p)
print(one)
print(other)
```

The output of the sides `one` and `other` seems to be the desired grouping:

```
[array([4. , 3. , 1.9]), array([4., 1., 2.])]
[array([2.5, 3. , 3. ]), array([2.5, 1.5, 3. ]), array([1.2, 3. , 3. ]), array([1.2, 1.5, 3. ]), array([2.2, 3. , 3.5]), array([2.2, 1.5, 3.5])]
```

Here is a script that renders a 3d plot of the different elements:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# surface points slightly reordered
cutting_surf = np.array([[3., 1., 3.], [3., 2., 3.], [3., 3., 3.],
                        [2., 1., 1.], [2., 2., 1.], [2., 3., 1.]])

# take three points, not all on the same line
# -> two vectors for the plane
corner = cutting_surf[0]
v1 = np.subtract(cutting_surf[1], corner)
v1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)

v2 = np.subtract(cutting_surf[3], corner)
v2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)

orth = np.cross(v1, v2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim((0.5, 3.5))
ax.set_ylim((0.5, 3.5))
ax.set_zlim((0.5, 3.5))

# plot the surface points
xs, ys, zs = ([p[i] for p in cutting_surf] for i in range(3))
ax.scatter3D(xs, ys, zs, color="grey", marker="+")

# our two plane vectors:
ax.plot([xs[0], xs[1]], [ys[0], ys[1]], [zs[0], zs[1]], color="grey", alpha=0.6)
ax.plot([xs[0], xs[3]], [ys[0], ys[3]], [zs[0], zs[3]], color="grey", alpha=0.6)
# the orthogonal vector, based on the corner point, in green
ax.plot([corner[0], corner[0] + orth[0]],
        [corner[1], corner[1] + orth[1]],
        [corner[2], corner[2] + orth[2]], color="green", alpha=0.6)

cleaned_points = np.array([[2.5, 3., 3.], [2.5, 1.5, 3.], [1.2, 3., 3.],
          [1.2, 1.5, 3.], [2.2, 3., 3.5], [2.2, 1.5, 3.5], [4. , 3. , 1.9],
          [4. , 1. , 2. ]])

for p in cleaned_points:
    # point relative to our corner:
    p_moved = np.subtract(p, corner)
    d = np.dot(orth, p_moved)
    ax.plot(*p, color="cyan" if d < 0 else "red", marker="D")
plt.show()
```

So here you can see the plane (grey lines), the orthogonal vector (green), and the separated "clean" points (cyan and red):
[image: Plot of surface points, orthogonal vector and separated "clean" points]

As a possible bonus, if you normalize the orthogonal vector, the dot product gives you the distance of the points to the plane, so you could merge the cleaning step into this one (see, e.g., https://mathinsight.org/distance_point_plane).